# Setuid does not work for my windows program hosted on a Linux server

Tags: linux, permissions, windows, setuid, smb

I compiled ExpressI.exe on a Windows system with Visual C++.  The file ExpressI.exe resides on a share mounted from Linux.

I need to permit only the program ExpressI.exe to access the `test` folder that contains ExpressI.exe on the Linux share.  So I logged on to the Linux server and set the owner of every file in the `test` folder to user vek and gave `setuid` permission on the executable file ExpressI.exe.   I got the idea from Jenny D on this link [How do I disable copy permissions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67777/how-do-i-disable-copy-permissions)

Now I'm running it on a Windows 10 machine (not under WINE) connected to the Linux share.

The problem is when some other user (not user 'vek') runs this executable file on Windows 10, they cannot access the `test` folder.

Please see below picture.  How can I resolve this problem?

[image: setuid won't work]

Comment: Windows exe files could not be run in Linux environments unless only through layers like Wine. And Wine does not support setuid.

Comment: Thanks siblynx, and in case of I'm run it on Windows 10 system not linux environment, is it still not work?

Comment: What is machine 192.168.10.254 you're trying to run it on? What OS does it run?

Comment: What does Windows 10 have to do with it?  What type of executable is it?  Is it a .NET executable?  Are you running it under WINE?  What does `file ExpressI.exe` say?

Comment: @siblynx, 192.168.10.254 is Linux version 2.6.18-348.1.1.el5 (mockbuild@builder10.centos.org) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)).

Comment: @Mikel, ExpressI.exe compile on Windows system with Visual C++, now I'm running it on Windows 10 machine (not under WINE) but this execute files (ExpressI.exe) host on Linux system. My require is permit only ExpressI.exe to access 'test' folder that are in same folder of ExpressI.exe.

Comment: unix perms are irrelevant to windows.  this question belongs on http://superuser.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on http://superuser.com/

Comment: @cas Since the files are on a Linux server, doesn't that satisfy "Using or administering a *nix desktop or server"?

Comment: @user3571241 - can you try and explain the setup you have? It's possible that the server sharing the Linux filesystem to the Windows 10 system might not be allowing the execution of files that are on this share. The software that does the sharing of Linux -> Windows systems is called Samba, so I'd start with its logs first to see if they tell you anything. If you can get some of these details into this Q we can reopen it and/or migrate it to SuperUser.

Comment: @slm, thanks for you help, this is log that I get it from cat /var/log/samba/smbd.log

It's too long to paste, so I'd host it on text file host web, please see this below link

[link]http://textuploader.com/5typi

Comment: @user3571241 - can you post the entire file or is that all of it? Also can you post your smb.conf file? It looks like some potential issues there that might be related.

Comment: @slm, Thanks again, This is full log of smbd.log 
http://textuploader.com/5tb5n!

And this for smb.conf
http://textuploader.com/5tb1s!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot affect a user in windows by setting the `setuid` bit in Linux.

Windows does not see or use the `setuid` bit on a file from a Linux server.

Windows has no concept or mechanism of `setuid`.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you think my answer is correct, please accept it by clicking the check mark.